# Footer not on bottom of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a footer class however it seems to be at the bottom of my `.body-wrap` class as opposed to the actual page.

```css
.body-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
}
.footer-wrap {
  border: 1px black solid;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 3em;
  margin-top: -3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="header-wrap">
          <a href="#menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle">
            <img class="hamburger-toggle" src="./img/menu.svg">
          </a>
          <img class="logo" src="./img/Spark.svg">
          <img class="text-logo" src="./img/Spark-grey-text.svg">
        </div>

        <div class="body-wrap">
          <h1>Hi Dave.</h1>
          <h2>Got an idea? Share it on Spark.</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-wrap">
          <p>footer text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm also using a bootstrap sidebar template. Found here: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why `position:fixed;` and `position: relative;` in the same class? remove  `position: relative;`

Comment: because you applied negative margin 
  ` margin-top: -3em;`

Comment: Still appears right in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add this code:

```
.footer-wrap {
        border: 1px black solid;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 10;
        height: 3em;
        margin-top: -3em;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

Comment: That's put it on the bottom ok, however it does not respond to page shrinking caused by the sidebar

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:fixed` with `bottom:0` it will remain stable at bottom of page

```css
.body-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
}
.footer-wrap {
  border: 1px black solid;
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 3em;
  margin-top: -3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="header-wrap">
          <a href="#menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle">
            <img class="hamburger-toggle" src="./img/menu.svg">
          </a>
          <img class="logo" src="./img/Spark.svg">
          <img class="text-logo" src="./img/Spark-grey-text.svg">
        </div>

        <div class="body-wrap">
          <h1>Hi Dave.</h1>
          <h2>Got an idea? Share it on Spark.</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-wrap">
          <p>footer text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0` on your `footer-wrap`. Check the update below!

```css
.body-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
}
.footer-wrap {
  border: 1px black solid;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 3em;
  margin-top: -3em;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="header-wrap">
          <a href="#menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle">
            <img class="hamburger-toggle" src="./img/menu.svg">
          </a>
          <img class="logo" src="./img/Spark.svg">
          <img class="text-logo" src="./img/Spark-grey-text.svg">
        </div>

        <div class="body-wrap">
          <h1>Hi Dave.</h1>
          <h2>Got an idea? Share it on Spark.</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-wrap">
          <p>footer text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.body-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
}
.footer-wrap {
  width:100%;
  border: 1px black solid;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 3em;
  margin-top: -3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="header-wrap">
          <a href="#menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle">
            <img class="hamburger-toggle" src="./img/menu.svg">
          </a>
          <img class="logo" src="./img/Spark.svg">
          <img class="text-logo" src="./img/Spark-grey-text.svg">
        </div>

        <div class="body-wrap">
          <h1>Hi Dave.</h1>
          <h2>Got an idea? Share it on Spark.</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-wrap">
          <p>footer text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add width and height to your `.body-wrap` and width to footer too. Changes footer position as in below codes.

```
.body-wrap {
  width:200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  background:#111;
  color:#fff;
}
.footer-wrap {
  border: 1px black solid;
  z-index: 9;
  height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  background:#f22;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
}
```